# Custom error pages in web.config file are not covering all url paths

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

In my `web.config` file I have specified some custom errors:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
   <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error" />
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

Now, some links, such as `http://mysite.com/dsflhsdff` will be properly redirected to `mysite.com/notfound`. But some links, like `https://mysite.com/videoconference/0/0/0` are handled by server itself - instead of my custom error page, I am getting IIS error page (file or dir not found). In example this link - `https://scyk.pl/forums/0/0/0` will produce proper 404 error (my custom error page).

What is happening here? Do I need to set up IIS custom errors manually? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If the page call is not pass the asp.net engine, then yes is handle by IIS.

You can do that [setup very easy if you have direct access to the iis](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true), but IIS gives you the option to setup this custom errors also direct from the web.config of your site. Here is an example for the 404 error:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

More info at: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Answer (score 1):

This is because ASP.NET never even knows that there has been a request for the .htm page. IIS will handle .htm pages by itself without involving ASP.NET at all.

You can get your custom page to show in one of two ways:

Get ASP.NET to process .htm pages: In IIS rightclick your website/virtual directory --> properties --> home directory/virtual directory tab --> "configuration" button under the "application settings" section --> Add the mapping.
Set the custom error page for IIS: In IIS rightclick your website/virtual directory --> properties --> custom errors tab --> set the 404 error to the page your error page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also handle this error in your Global.asax file in  **Application_Error** method

e.g.

```
  void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

        // Handle HTTP errors
        if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
            // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
            // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
            // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
            /*if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
                return;*/

            //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
            /*Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");*/
        }
    }
```

More info :
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because IIS is unable to locate your custom error page in some instances. This happened to me with certain extensions, but by configuring my custom error page in the Error Pages portion of IIS manager I was able to hit my custom error page every time.

Heres how to do that:

Go into your IIS Manager and select the site in question, find the icon entitled 'Error Pages' under the IIS section.

After you double click the icon, you will be presented with a list of status codes and the corresponding file responsible for delivering the error.

Find the error code, in your case 404 (if it does not exist you can add it from the right side menu by clicking on 'Add...'), then click on the 'Edit...' button in the right side menu.

Next, click the radio button for 'Execute a URL on this site' in the dialog box you have been presented with. Here is where you provide the relative URL that the user will be redirected to.

After you have completed the options in the Edit dialog box, you are going to want to select your page in the main Error Pages pain again, only this time click 'Edit Feature Settings...'

In the Edit Error Pages Settings you are presented with, ensure that 'Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requests' is selected. Also ensure the page you entered in the previous Edit menu is entered in the Path field in the Default Page portion of the Edit Error Pages dialog box. Finally, Path Type must be set to 'Execute URL'